# Custom keyboard shortcuts dont work after reboot

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I added keyboard shortcut for `gnome-terminal` (I preffer this one). When I just create it, it works. After reboot it does not, so I assume something does not start properly on boot.

1. Can I add it manually, without system settings, willing that it would work.
2. Whats the process I should turn on and how?

**Btw. I use Arch linux with pantheon.**

Answer (score 1):

Please consider asking your question on an Arch forum *(like [bbs.archlinux.org](https://bbs.archlinux.org/index.php))*, because I'm not sure if these commands apply on Arch.
On eOS I can use `gsettings` to change the keybindings via terminal.

First `get` the current binding with your logged in user:
`gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys terminal`
The output is something like:
`'<Primary><Alt>t'`

To change this, you can use:
`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys terminal` "YOUR-KEYS"
Use the same syntax as in the output earlier and put it in quotation marks. As far as I know, gsettings doesn't check if these keybindings are already in use, so to be sure just try them, before hitting the `set` command.
After that you can rerun the `get` command, to check if it worked or hit the keys you specified.

---

***EDIT:*** I think, I misunderstood what you want..
In the case you want to change the default terminal-*application*, the commands would be:

*Get the current value and the correct syntax:*
`gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec`
Example output: `'pantheon-terminal'`

*Set gnome-terminal as default:*
`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec "'gnome-terminal'"`